# fill_between not filling consistently

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using python 3.4.1, matplotlib 1.4, ipython 2.3 notebook, Arch Linux.

I'm trying to plot division of a plane by a line into two parts, for example two regions of classification, where one region has one value, and other region other value. I'm interested in region in interval [-1, 1]x[-1, 1].

Here is an example where everything works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a, b = (2.5711100440212684, -0.87718711444141584)
x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.001)
y1 = a*x + b
y2 = -1
y3 = 1
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y1>y2, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y3, where=y1<y3, facecolor='yellow', interpolate=True)
plt.axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])
```

This code gives me a picture as I think it should:
[image]

On the other hand, if I change a slope a bit, here's what I get:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a, b = (4.5711100440212684, -0.87718711444141584)
x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.001)
y1 = a*x + b
y2 = -1
y3 = 1
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y1>y2, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y3, where=y1<y3, facecolor='yellow', interpolate=True)
plt.axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])
```

[image]

It's possible that I'm missing something. If anyone sees the mistake, please let me know.

EDIT: Oh yes, green filling seems to work for all values of slope well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Using Matplotlib nightly build, Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.4, **but running it from the console**. Did you try that too?

[image]

Comment: I did now, and I still get this. It seems it's some kind of a bug. Could you check your matplotlib version? It might be matplotlib 1.4.0 bug.

Comment: 1.5.x and the build is: https://launchpad.net/~takluyver/+archive/ubuntu/matplotlib-daily

Comment: OK, thanks, it must be a bug then. I will upvote and accept your answer.